# Finding intersecting points of a circle inside a triangle

Tags: circles

If I have a triangle, and I wanted to place a circle with a given diameter that fits snuggly inside any one of the three angles, how can I find the x, y points of where the triangle and circle meet?

Comment: Follow-up question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266554/finding-tangent-points-of-circle-inside-a-triangle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a hint:  if the diameter is $d$ and the angle at a specific vertex is $\alpha$ then the distances from that vertex along each side is $$ \frac{d}{2} \times \frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}.$$

[image]

Comment: Very interesting idea. I will play arond with this. Thanks so much.

Comment: @David When you write a follow-up question, like you did at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266554/finding-tangent-points-of-circle-inside-a-triangle , it's a good idea to link the questions to each other, as I did in comments. SE software detects intrasite links and puts them in the `Linked` sidebar on the right.